# Toggle ngb-tooltip in sortable mat-table header with javascript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, ng-bootstrap, mat-table

Does anybody know if is it even possible to manipulate bootstrap ngb-tooltip placed in sortable mat-table using typescript?

I can do this for all elements everywhere in my code except header of sortable mat-table. I think the reason is I already have

```
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
```

and it's probably related to column header defined like this

```
 <ng-container matColumnDef="CustomerPoNumber">
    <th class="text-light text-left pl-1 pr-1" mat-header-cell 
      *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Customer<br>Po Number
    </th>
    <td class="text-left pl-1 pr-1 text-nowrap" mat-cell 
      *matCellDef="let row">
      {{row.CustomerPoNumber | replaceText: '\\s':'-'}}</td>
  </ng-container>
```

And when I add to th element

```
[autoClose]="true" ngbTooltip="Click" #tooltip5="ngbTooltip"
```

my ts code

```
  @ViewChild('tooltip5') tooltip5: NgbTooltip;
```

says tooltip5 is not defined.

But when I move tooltip defining line to another element outside mat-table it works perfectly. Do you know how to workaround this?